# Where are photos imported via iPhoto stored on disk?

Tags: photos.app

I imported some photos from iPhoto and want to attach them to an email message after exporting them.

However, Pictures -> iPhoto Library is not a folder. Where is the actual folder that these photos are stored in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**iPhoto Library → Right-Click → Show Package Contents**

You have to search for your pictures. The order is not logical - i.e. sorted by events.

It's easier to choose the following options if you send an email:

- In iPhoto go to **Share → Email** or ...
- ...export your pictures so that you can attach them manually **File → Export**

#### Why is the iPhoto Library stored in a package?

The reason is actually quite simple: People break things. When you accidentally mess around with the pictures by unintentionally moving them - you break the library. Photo Booth has its own package for the same reason.

However, if you want to have control over the hierarchy of your picture folders in Finder, you should not import pictures into iPhoto. The setting is located at *iPhoto Preferences → Advanced → Importing*.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I wish the interface were a bit clearer about this. What do you mean by "send the email from within of iPhoto"?

Comment: @DavidFaux I've updated the answer to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Within iPhoto, you can also right-click on a photo and choose **Show File**. This will bring up the photo file in the Finder without having to browse for it. As the other answer says, though, there aren't very many circumstances under which this is a good idea, since most photo management and sharing can be done from within iPhoto.